# What is the most efficient way to have airflow trigger a python script?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a local airflow environment and a couple scripts that I want to schedule to run.  I am working on creating a DAG file for each.  What is the most efficient way to trigger a python script to run?

I can use a PythonOperator in the DAG and have all my code in one file, but this seems overly busy.

I like the idea of using the DAG file to trigger a stand alone python script, but I am having a hard time implementing this.  My DAG cannot locate my python script in a different folder.  My current folder structure is:

- airflow_docker

  - dags

    - example_dag.py
  - scripts

    - example_script.py

I want example_dag.py to run example_script.py.

Which way is the most scalable and why? Or is there a better way I am not thinking of?

Here is my current dag:

```
    with DAG(
    dag_id='example_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='This dag serves as a way to validate my local airflow environment.',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 30),
    schedule_interval='@hourly',
    template_searchpath=["Users/<username>/Documents/airflow_docker/scripts"]
    ) as dag:
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        bash_command=("pwd")
    )
    task2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task2',
        bash_command=("python example_script.py")
    )
    
    task1 >> task2
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing definition for `template_searchpath`

```
dag = DAG(
    ...
    template_searchpath=["/home/airflow/scripts"],
)
```

Executing Python scripts is done by using `BashOperator`:

```
run_this = BashOperator(
    task_id="run",
    bash_command="python example_script.py",
)
```

for Airflow to find the script it must either be in relative path with the DAG or if not then path must be added to [`template_searchpath`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c1aa4b9500f417e6669a79fbf59c11ae6e6993a2/airflow/models/dag.py#L289-L292) since in your case the path is not relative then adding the path to `template_searchpath` solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am still getting the following error: python: can't open file 'example_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.  I added my current DAG to the problem statement.

Comment: Note that your deploted Airflow in docker. The paths you see in your desktop are not the paths in the docker. You will need to browse the docker file tree and choose the correct paths. You need to set relative paths to the root